# How do I get web config transforms to work with Web Deployment Projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

I installed Visual Studio Web Deployment Projects 2010 and added a deployment project to my solution.  When I build the deployment project, it does not apply the web.config transform file for the specified configuration.

My web app project has the following files:
Web.config
Web.Debug.config
Web.Release.config
Web.Stage.config

I have tried to check the "Enable web.config file section replacement" but that seems to not make a difference.  I even tried checking "Use external configuration source file" but that didn't make a difference either.

I've tested the config files using MSBuild from the command line and they work as expected.

Do web deployment projects support config transformations?  If so, how do I get them to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work and used [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) functionality instead.  Web deploy supports web.config transforms and seems to be a bit more flexible than web deployment projects.